# Processing 100,000 records update in a jdbc batch

Tags: java, jdbc

I am inserting 132,000 records in a database table using jdbc batch of prepated statement. The problem i am facing is all records are not inserted in to table only records 1444 are inserted.

```
try{
        StringBuffer insert = new StringBuffer("INSERT INTO mytable (field1,field2,
,field3,field 4 )   VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? )");

          pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(insert.toString());
          Iterator cptIcd9Iterator = cptIcd9List.iterator();    
          while(cptIcd9Iterator.hasNext()){
              cptIcd9VO = (CptIcd9VO)cptIcd9Iterator.next();            
              count++;
              pstmt.setString(1, "field1");
              pstmt.setString(2, "field2");
              pstmt.setString(3, "field3");
              pstmt.setInt(4, 4);
              pstmt.addBatch();
          }
           updateCounts = pstmt.executeBatch();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e);
   }
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: you're not giving enough information, does it produce an error along the way for example?

Comment: No it does not give any error. It quits normally without any exception or error

Comment: what's in updateCounts at the end? does this flag success for 1444 rows only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't insert all of them in one go, you must do it step by step.

Read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227596/jdbc-batch-insert-outofmemoryerror).