# How to increase the size of staging tables in ODI

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

What is the maximum size of the staging table in ODI?? 
And is there any way in which u can increase the size of the staging tables in Oracle Data Integrator?

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "increase". There is no practical limit on an Oracle table, so are you getting an error? If so, we need to see that error

Comment: Suppose there is huge amount of data in source , so the staging table is created according to the source or is there any limit to the staging table??

Comment: There is no real limit on a table. There might be on the tablespace in which the data is stored for that table. But I guess you should ask the question to your DBA.

Comment: As said from others there is no limit in table size. Only issue which can occur is when you load data by jdbc is to reach memory limits when not slicing in batches https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227596/jdbc-batch-insert-outofmemoryerror